# I am trying to make a phone validation program in java, why am I getting a 'else without if' error?

Tags: java, syntax-error

I am trying to do an extra credit assignment with phone number validation from a file. Most of the structuring was provided by the teacher and I had to fill in or add certain parts. I keep getting an 'else without if' error and from what I can see I didn't include any ';' after if/else/else if statements so I don't know why I am getting this error.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.lang.model.util.ElementScanner6;
import java.io.*;   
import static java.lang.System.*; 


public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {       
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("ValidPhoneNumber.dat"));  
            
    int lines = input.readLine();
        
        input.nextLine();
        
        String phoneNumber = ' ';
         
        for (int i=0; i<lines; i++)
        {
         phoneNumber = input.nextLine;
            
            if (phoneNumber.length() == 14) 
            {
                out.println("Valid");}
                
               else{
         out.println("Invalid"); 
               
            }
            else if (phoneNumber.length() == 12) //error here
            {
                out.println("Valid");}

                else
            {out.println("Invalid");

            }
            else //error here
            {
                out.print("Invalid");
           
            }
        
        }
        
        input.close();

    } 

}
```

The error is on line 63 and line 72

```
else if (phoneNumber.length() == 12)
```

and

```
 else 
            {
                out.print("Invalid");
            }
```

Comment: because that `if` already has an `else`. You can't have two. `else if` is like writing `else { if { ...`.

Comment: You can have one of the two. 1. if then else, or if, else if, else if, ....else

Comment: I think what you're not seeing is that you have a spurious `else` clause in the middle of your code (`else{ out.println("Invalid"); }` appears twice in your code).

Comment: Try using your IDE reformating tool to properly see how your code is layed out. Usually, this helps finding the reason why that issue appears.

Comment: What helps is to follow code style guidelines and not put braces sometimes on one sometimes on another line, or sometimes changing the indent for no reason. This makes it WAY easier to parse the code and see immediately, that there's "if else else" which is invalid syntax.

Answer (score 1):

In the first error you need to remove `else` word.
In the second error you need to do the same, or change the condition of the `else` under the first error to use it.
You're calling `else` two times sequentially in both errors.
To resume: You're calling `else` without a `if` (the error shows it).

```
if(){
}else{
 }

if(){
} else if(){
  }else{
   }
```

That's the correct way to use `if`, `else if` and `else`. In your code, it applies.

In this link you will see the explanation:
[How to use if and else](https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/if-else-statement)

Answer (score 0):

Valid options

```
 1. Only if
 2. if...else
 3. if...elseif...else
```

You cant write if..else followed by else if.

Correct that and it will work

Answer (score 0):

You misplaced your

```
 else{
```

you put it inside the braces in front of if, and therefore there is no if *in that block* preceding the else statement, hence if without else.
pull it out of there and put it after the brace that closes the open brace after if.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to specify multiple conditions, then you should use `if` -> multiple `else if` -> `else`, what means that `else` block is the last one.
As explained above, the new code must look like the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
    phoneNumber = input.nextLine;
    if (phoneNumber.length() == 14) {
        out.println("Valid");
    } else if (phoneNumber.length() == 12) {
        out.println("Valid");
    } else {
        out.println("Invalid");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
    phoneNumber = input.nextLine;
    if (phoneNumber.length() == 14 || phoneNumber.length() == 12 ) {
        out.println("Valid");
    } else {
        out.println("Invalid");
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you should include some explanation of why this solves the problem. That would make it much more useful to the OP so that they can understand what they were doing wrong.